# dplyr filter not working as expected in function with same argument names

Tags: r, dplyr, plumber

I wrote the following simple `plumber api`

```r
library(plumber)
library(dplyr)


#* @apiTitle TESTS API

#* Returns json with filtered mtcars
#* @param carb 
#* @param gear 
#* @get /test2
#* @serializer unboxedJSON
function(carb,gear) {
  mtcars %>% filter(gear == as.numeric(gear),
                    carb == as.numeric(carb)) %>% 
    jsonlite::toJSON()

}
```

Alas, when I call it the mtcars data is not filtered as I would expect:

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
response <- GET(url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3098/test2', 
                query = list(gear = 4,
                             carb = 4),
                encode="json")
content(response, encoding = "json") %>% fromJSON() %>% head()

   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work differently if you use `dplyr::filter` instead of just `filter`?

Comment: no, using `dplyr::filter` makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` and friends<sup>1</sup> are smart, but they cannot differentiate between the two references to `gear` (and `carb`). For instance, in `gear == as.numeric(gear)`, you intend the first to refer to `gear` within the frame and the second to refer to the function argument, but in these functions, the first match of `gear` (to within the frame, within the function environment, within the enclosing environments) wins and is used for all references. In this case, they both match the column of the frame, and are therefore always `TRUE` (in this example).

Try:

```r
function(carb., gear.) {
  mtcars %>% filter(gear == as.numeric(gear.),
                    carb == as.numeric(carb.)) %>% 
    jsonlite::toJSON()

}
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect that the API arguments are less aesthetic. So if you want to preserve the way they look (or there are external motivators to keeping them as-is), then do a quick reassignment.

```r
function(carb, gear) {
  c. <- carb
  g. <- gear
  mtcars %>%
    filter(gear == as.numeric(g.),
           carb == as.numeric(c.)) %>% 
    jsonlite::toJSON()
}
```

Side note: I find it useful at times to implement permissive filtering, where an omitted (or intentionally-null) argument means no filtering.

```r
function(carb = NA, gear = NA) {
  c. <- carb
  g. <- gear
  mtcars %>%
    filter(is.na(g.) | gear == as.numeric(g.),
           is.na(c.) | carb == as.numeric(c.)) %>% 
    jsonlite::toJSON()
}
```

Another side note: is there a reason you are doing a double JSON here? For instance, I'm seeing:

```sh
$ curl -s localhost:8000/test2?gear=4
"[{\"mpg\":21,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":160,\"hp\":110,\"drat\":3.9,\"wt\":2.62,\"qsec\":16.46,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":4},...]"
```

which is returning a long string (note the quotes). Many parsers will see that as a string and preserve it. (For instance, piping `curl ... | jq .` does not break-open the json as it should, it just returns the literal string.)

Instead, if you remove the `toJSON`, you see:

```sh
$ curl -s localhost:8000/test2?gear=4
[{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4},...]
```

which is a "proper" json return, and can be parsed correctly. Adding `| jq .` after the curl call correctly parses the output:

```sh
$ curl -s localhost:8000/test2?gear=4 | jq .
[
  {
    "mpg": 21,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.62,
    "qsec": 16.46,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4
  },
  ...
]
```

---

Notes:

1. I should note that this is not unique to `dplyr`, and there should be no blame assigned there. The same behavior can be seen with `base::with` and `base::within`. Compare the two:

   ```r
   func <- function(carb, gear) { browser(); 1; }
   func(1, 3)
   # Called from: func(1, 3)
   debug at #1: [1] 1
   c. <- carb
   g. <- gear
   with(mtcars, { gear == as.numeric(gear) & carb == as.numeric(carb); })
   #  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   # [16] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   # [31] TRUE TRUE
   with(mtcars, { gear == as.numeric(g.) & carb == as.numeric(c.); })
   #  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just unquote them with `!!`:

```r
function(carb,gear) {
  mtcars %>% filter(gear == as.numeric(!! gear),
                    carb == as.numeric(!! carb)) %>% 
    jsonlite::toJSON()

}
```

See [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).